# XSLT - Recursive loop base case

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML input document:

```
<root>
  <MultiItem name="m1">
    <MultiItem name="m2">
      <SingleItemA name="s1A" >
        <SingleItemB name="s1B"/>
      </SingleItemA >
      <SingleItemB name="s2B" />
    </MultiItem>
    <SingleItemB name="s3B" />
    <MultiItem name="m3">
      <SingleItemA name="s2A" >
        <MultiItem name ="m4">
          <SingleItemA name="s3A"/>
        </MultiItem>
      </SingleItemA>
      <MultiItem name="m5">
        <SingleItemB name="s4B" />
        <SingleItemA name="s4A" >
          <SingleItemA name="s5A" />
        </SingleItemA>
      </MultiItem>
    </MultiItem>
  </MultiItem>
</root>
```

This contains `<MultiItem>` nodes that can contain any amount of either `<SingleItemA>`, `<SingleItemB>` or `<MultiItem>` nodes. And `<SingleItem>` nodes that contain only one node.

There is also no limit to the amount of nested `<MultiItem>`nodes so something like this could happen:

```
<MultiItem>
  <MultiItem>
    <MultiItem>
      <MultiItem>
        <MultiItem>
          <MultiItem>
            <SingleItemA />
          </MultiItem>
        </MultiItem>
      </MultiItem>
    </MultiItem>
  </MultiItem>
</MultiItem>
```

I need to write an xslt template that recursively loops through all elements while counting the amount of `<SingleItemA>` nodes. Based on this count a different templates will be applied. This is all part of a much larger XSLT transform so an `apply-templates` call will not work.

I also only care about the first level elements within the `<MultiItem>` node. If a `<SingleItemA>` node is inside another `<SingleItemA>` node, I don't want it counted. However if a `<MultiItem>` node is inside another `<MultiItem>` node, I need to check for `<SingleItemA>` nodes within it. For the above example the count would be 3 because of `<SingleItemA>` nodes with name s1A, s2A, s4A

This is the template I have come up with so far and it is called from a template that matches `<MultiItem>` like <`xsl:call template name='GetCountAndAppy.>` with param count equal to zero:

```
 <xsl:template name="GetCountAndApply">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'MultiItem'">
          <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetCountAndApply">
              <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'SingleItemA'">
          <xsl:call-template name="GetCountAndApply">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/> <!-- skip to next child -->
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test="'HasLoopedThroughEverything[NEED A WAY TO TELL]'">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$count  > 1">
          <!--Apply templates-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <!--Apply different templates-->
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have been unable to figure out a case to put into the if loop in order to tell that there is nothing else to loop through. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this, or where I am going wrong in my thought process. XSLT is fairly new to me.

Comment: You don't need such a complicated approach (which is not currently going to work as you would need to return a value from your template, and sum up the results each time). You can just get the count simply by doing `<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(.//SingleItemA)" />`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have realized that I oversimplified what the problem is. I don't want a count of all SingleItemA nodes just the higher level ones. . I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You still don't really need your recursive template. Although there is probably a better way (especially if you can use XSLT 3.0), you could try doing this:

```
<xsl:variable name="ancestorCount" select="count(ancestor::SingleItemA)" />
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(.//SingleItemA[count(ancestor::SingleItemA) = $ancestorCount])" />
```

Comment: Does this solution require XSLT 3.0? I can only use 1.0

Comment: This is indeed an XSLT 1.0 solution.